# Selectig a row with a column value that exists only when another column has got just certain value

Tags: mysql, sql

Please, consider the following MySQL table

```
|----+--------+----------|
| id | result |reference | 
|----+--------+----------|
|  1 |ok      |       33 |
|  2 |ok      |       46 | 
|  3 |ko      |       55 |  
|  4 |ko      |       55 |  
|  5 |ok      |       55 |  
|  6 |ko      |       47 | 
|  7 |ko      |       89 |  
|  8 |ok      |       91 | 
|  9 |ko      |       47 |  
+----+--------+----------+
```

I want to select the row whose result = ko and reference = 47 because the reference 47 doesn't exist in any row whose result = ok. In addition to that I want this row just once, as this case occurs twice (id=6 and id=9), although it could occur once. In fact in the query I'm asking for, the row with id=89 should appear as well, as reference = 89, result = ko and there is no other row with reference = 89 and result = ok.
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [subquery with not exists](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) :

```
SELECT DISTINCT result, reference 
FROM [dbo].[references] as x
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[references] as y
 WHERE
 y.reference = x.reference
 and
 y.result = 'ok');
```

You could also do it with a self left join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.result, x.reference 
FROM [dbo].[references] as x
LEFT JOIN
[dbo].[references] as y 
on x.reference = y.reference
and y.result = 'ok'
WHERE
y.reference IS NULL
```

Comment: Thaks a lot, Dugas! I think the first solution you gave me before is ok. I mean.. SELECT DISTINCT estado, referencia FROM envios WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM envios AS tableA2 WHERE envios.estado = 'exito') But now imagine that instead of having just three columns I had seven and I wanted to retrieve them all. How could I do it. In the query you mentioned at the beginning you retrieve just two columns but I want all seven. Thanks for taking time to help me. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Just add them to the first select.

Comment: Thanks duga, It worked perfectly. I used the second option and the results are just what i needed! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Use conditionals, something to the effect of:

```
IF EXISTS (Select TOP 1 * from <thistable>
WHERE result='OK' AND reference=47)
SELECT Select TOP 1 * from <thistable>
WHERE result='OK' AND reference=47
ELSE
SELECT Select TOP 1 * from <thistable>
WHERE result='KO' AND reference=47
END
```

Comment: Hi Voices, thanks for your time. Tho second option of duga was wxactly what i was looking for. Greetings!